# Should we be concerned about possible copyright infringement?

Tags: discussion, questions

This is my first visit to Web Applications, although I've been using the other SE sites for some time.

I left some comments on [this](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/15777/whats-the-best-way-to-trasnfer-copy-you-tube-videos-to-other-account) question.

It kind of escalated. Did **I** overreact and overstep the mark?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Perhaps a bit, yes, but thank you for raising the issue on meta.

See this related Super User answer

https://meta.superuser.com/questions/2212/is-discussion-of-techniques-for-removing-drm-permitted/2215#2215

TL;DR -- we *always assume fair use* unless there is clear and compelling evidence of illegal or dangerous intentions.

I think this is a perfectly valid and useful WebApps question for someone who wanted to move all their YouTube videos -- whether they are of their dog, or of The Black Eyed Peas -- to another video hosting site for whatever reason.

Comment: Ok, point taken @Jeff. I was drawn into an exchange of commments which I should have avoided in the first place. If I come back to Webmasters I'll follow my own advice <http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89367/i-am-a-new-user-of-stack-overflow> and read until I get a flavour of what's acceptable. Thanks.